# How do I get a wicket link inside a label?

Tags: wicket

I've got a simple text on my page which needs localizing, but it contains a link.  How do I localize it?

```
Click <a href="/ercc/releasenotes">here</a>
    for the release notes.
```

So I need to be able to have that in German:

```
Klicken Sie hier fur die release notes
```

It's currently a simple static link in the html.  Obviously I will need to create a Link object on the page, but how do I get the link inside the label, and the whole thing localised?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is answered in the [Wicket Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Everything+about+Wicket+internationalization#EverythingaboutWicketinternationalization-Puttingwicketcomponentsintothemessage)

Comment: Even if your answer is correct, link-only answers are subject to link rott and thus not really helpfull. [The help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) suggests to at least quote or paraphrase the relevant part in your answer.